# Правильное написание местоимения "вы"

Tags: орфография

С заглавной или со строчной буквы следует писать местоимение "вы" в справочном тексте?

Comment: Что значит в справочном тексте?

Answer (score 1):

Местоимение "вы" пишется с большой буквы только в том случае, если имеет место обращение к конкретному одному лицу. Например, как я сейчас обращаюсь к Вам. В справочном тексте Вы обращаетесь к абстрактному читателю, а то и не к одному, следовательно "вы" будет со строчной буквы.